# How convince people who are extremely skeptical of science, statistics, and expert authority in general, that science is not always bunk?

Tags: discussion

I'm thinking here of some kind of primer, blog, etc. for the general public on how these fields can be trusted, but skeptically, and not a review of statistics, etc. I raise this from frustrations with people who think that any argument that cites a reliable authority (e.g., Census data) is not worth considering. Sort of the "well, anybody can find a study" crowd. While I admire skepticism, and understand & even advocate for a healthy distrust of experts, what is a good argument, reading, youtube video, etc. for dealing with "motivated reasoning" that just discounts all evidence? Sorry if this is too broad.

Comment: Tell them about polio and cholera? This question doesn't fit on this site but could maybe be asked on the philosophy or science education sites, or on quora?

Comment: Simple answer: you can't, at least short of e.g. brainwashing.  If they could be convinced by reason or observation, they already would be.

Comment: Explaining how the GPS on their phones works is another good one: how laws of physics are used to put 32 satellites into orbit and predict exactly where they'll all be at any moment, how silicon chemistry is used to generate solar power to constantly transmit radio waves (also explain how scientists discovered radio waves in the first place), then talk through the maths of how to calculate your position down to 5 meters from the time signals from the four closest satelites. Lots of amazing but easy to explain parts, and the evidence it works is in most people's pockets used almost every day

Comment: Another good thing about GPS is it illustrates incremental improvements and in science or tech nothing is final and there's always room for further study and improvement: you can show how it's a big incremental improvement over previous land-based systems, and how there's still room for improvement (e.g. that it doesn't work under a roof / ground the radio waves can't get through, and that it's managed by one organisation who could choose to turn it off or deny access)

Comment: There are many reasons why you can't. One, various cognitive biases. Two, unfortunately those people do have a point. Many experts either consciously or unconsciously produce bad results (ref: the study on how many medical studies and separately how many psychology studies were not replicable).  Or, for fields where my personal expertise is, look at all the financial "experts" who shrilly predicted stock market crash if Trump won elections (without shorting the index, to prove their confidence, natch).